# lldb and C code give different results for pow()

Tags: c, debugging, int, lldb

I have one variable, `Npart` which is an `int` and initialized to `64`. Below is my code (`test.c`):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int Npart, N;

int main(){

Npart = 64;

N = (int) (pow(Npart/1., (1.0/3.0)));
printf("%d %d\n",Npart, N);

return 0;
};
```

which prints out `64 3`, probably due to numerical precision issues. I compile it as follows:

```
gcc -g3 test.c -o test.x
```

If I try to debug using `lldb`, I try to calculate the value and print it in the command prompt, the following happens:

```
$ lldb ./test.x
(lldb) target create "./test.x"
Current executable set to './test.x' (x86_64).
(lldb) breakpoint set --file test.c --line 1
Breakpoint 1: where = test.x`main + 44 at test.c:8, address = 0x0000000100000f0c
(lldb) r
Process 20532 launched: './test.x' (x86_64)
Process 20532 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5279e0, 0x0000000100000f0c test.x`main + 44 at test.c:8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x0000000100000f0c test.x`main + 44 at test.c:8
   5    
   6    int main(){
   7    
-> 8    Npart = 64;
   9    
   10   N = (int) (pow(Npart/1., (1.0/3.0)));
   11   printf("%d %d\n",Npart, N);
(lldb) n
Process 20532 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5279e0, 0x0000000100000f12 test.x`main + 50 at test.c:10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
frame #0: 0x0000000100000f12 test.x`main + 50 at test.c:10
   7    
   8    Npart = 64;
   9    
-> 10   N = (int) (pow(Npart/1., (1.0/3.0)));
   11   printf("%d %d\n",Npart, N);
   12   
   13   return 0;
(lldb) n
Process 20532 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5279e0, 0x0000000100000f4a test.x`main + 106 at test.c:11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f4a test.x`main + 106 at test.c:11
   8    Npart = 64;
   9    
   10   N = (int) (pow(Npart/1., (1.0/3.0)));
-> 11   printf("%d %d\n",Npart, N);
   12   
   13   return 0;
   14   };
(lldb) print Npart
(int) $0 = 64
(lldb) print (int)(pow(Npart/1.,(1.0/3.0)))
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
(int) $1 = 0
(lldb) print (int)(pow(64,1.0/3.0))
(int) $2 = 0
```

Why is `lldb` giving different results?

**Edit:** Clarified the question and provided a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Olaf Please see the updated question. Thank you for taking the time to explain the reason behind the downvote.

Comment: First of all, you're flooring `n` which would be the least sane thing to do (use round/nearbyint/rint/whatever)

Comment: second, I have a vague feeling that `lldb` doesn't know that `pow` returns a `double`, and it thinks it returns an *int*. Please print the return value without any casts!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Am I flooring `N`? How so? `lldb` doesn't know what `pow` returns `error: 'pow' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type` when I don't cast `int`.

Comment: You are flooring `N` by casting to `int`, which truncates the fractional part. Why not use `round()` or `lround()`?

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, I noticed that at one point and fixed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code calculates the cube root of 64, which should be 4.

The C code converts the return value to an integer by *flooring* it. The `pow` is usually implemented in some sort of Taylor polynomial or similar - this tends to be numerically inaccurate. The result on your computer seems to be a little less than 4.0, which when cast to `int` is *truncated* - the solution would be to use for example `lround` first instead:

```
N = lround(pow(Npart/1., (1.0/3.0)));
```

---

As for the `lldb`, the key is the text:

```
error: 'pow' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
```

i.e. it *doesn't* know the return type - thus the prototype - of the function. `pow` is declared as

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

but since the only hint that `lldb` has about the return type is the cast you provided, `lldb` thinks the prototype is

```
int pow(int x, double y);
```

and that will lead into undefined behaviour - in practice, `lldb` thinks that the return value should be the `int` from the EAX register, hence `0` was printed, but the actual return value was in some floating point/SIMD register. Likewise, since the types of the arguments are not known either, you must not pass in an `int`.

Thus I guess you would get the proper value in the debugger with

```
print (double)(pow(64.0, 1.0/3.0))
```

Comment: To reduce debug information size, most compilers only emit function prototypes in the debug info for the dylib that defines the function.  You don't have debug info for libC, so lldb won't know the signature of pow, as Antti rightly points out.  But if you're on macOS you can issue the command: `expr -l objc -- @import Darwin` which will cause lldb to build the Darwin module - including all the standard C library defines, and load that into the expression parser.  That will provide lldb with the prototypes for all the standard C functions, and then you can call them without casting.

Comment: @JimIngham might be worth a separate answer! I am not a Mac user :/